# binding of array elements in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Basiclly I have an Array of some Strings and I want to bind each of this strings to an circle. Then when I hover over the Circle I want to display these strings in a tooltip.

So this is my Array:

```
var node = [
        "Hallo Hallo Hallo Hallo Hallo Hallo Hallo",
        "foobarbaz",
        "This is a short text",
        "Changed some things on the folder structure and added some functions to the convert.c file",
    ];
```

Then there is my Tooltip which displays a html text...

```
var tooltip = svg.append('foreignObject')
        .attr('x', 50)
        .attr('y', 50)
        .attr('width', 200)
        .attr('height', 300)
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .append("xhtml:body")
        .html('<div style="width: 150px;">Example</div>');
```

And now I want to create my circles over a for loop, append the data to them and let the tooltip display the right data on a mouseover:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

    svg.append("circle")
        .data(node[i])
        .attr("cx", 100*i+250)
        .attr("cy", 100)
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", "steelblue" )
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            return tooltip.style("visibility","visible")
                .html('<div style="width: 150px;">'+d+'</div>');
        }).on("mouseout", function(){
            return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
        });
    }
```

But for some reason the result is not the whole string when I hover over the points it is just the fist character of the string. I am obviously missing something here...

Comment: Use `.datum()` instead of `.data()`. You really shouldn't be using a loop here though but D3's selections and data matching.

Comment: Ok i sovled it with the answer of Oleg. I modified the solution a bit: var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                 .data(node)
                 .enter()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 expects you to provide an array of values, such as `.data([1,2,3,4])`. You are passing in strings instead. So, D3 tries to match individual characters of a string (because a string, just like an array, can be iterated over) to the elements of the selection. In this case there's already one element, so it will assign to it the `__data__` property equal to the first character of the string. The rest of the characters will go to the `enter` selection.

As Lars Kotthoff mentioned in his comment, you shouldn't be using `for` loops when working with D3. Instead, try something like this:

```
svg.selectAll('circle') // empty (yet) selection of circles
  .data(node) // apply data to the empty selection, where node is your array of strings
  .enter() // same as "for all entering (new) elements... "
    .append('circle') // creates as many circles as there are elements in node array
    .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
        // d is "Hello...", "foobarbaz", "This is a short text", etc.
        // i is 0, 1, 2, 3
        return 100 * i + 250; // dynamic, index-dependent x
    })
    .attr('cy', 100) // constant y value across all elements
    .on('mouseover', function (d) {
      console.log(d);
    });
```

Comment: Ok but how can I than access the iterator?

Comment: You don't need to access the iterator. `.data([1,2,3]).enter()` is similar to `[1,2,3].forEach()`. It does the iteration for you (and computes a data join, so it's like iteration on steroids).

Comment: I want to place the circles in with the same distance depanding on the element id so actually need the iterator.

Comment: `attr`, among other methods, can take a function as the second argument and D3 passes in the datum and the index of the currently iterated element. The returned value is assigned to the attribute. See updated code in answer.